# How to extract nested ejabberd message element from MucSub event in Erlang

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I want to find message element in ejabberd packet.
The packet itself is a message element but sometimes (delayed messages or other cases) the actual message is nested inside the packet:

Normal messages:

```
<message from="hag66@shakespeare.example"
         to="coven@muc.shakespeare.example"
         type="groupchat">
  <body>Test</body>
</message>
```

Other structures example:

```
<message from="coven@muc.shakespeare.example"
         to="hag66@shakespeare.example/pda">
  <event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event">
    <items node="urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages">
      <item id="18277869892147515942">
        <message from="coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch"
                 to="hag66@shakespeare.example/pda"
                 type="groupchat"
                 xmlns="jabber:client">
          <archived xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp"
                    by="muc.shakespeare.example"
                    id="1467896732929849" />
          <stanza-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0"
                     by="muc.shakespeare.example"
                     id="1467896732929849" />
          <body>Hello from the MUC room !</body>
        </message>
      </item>
    </items>
  </event>
</message>
```

Which in second example I would like to find the inner message element.
The second case structure is not always the same. So I need to traverse trough the packet and try to find any sub element with name message.
It cannot be two message subelements so if I found the first I don't need to continue anymore. If there were no sub elements with name message I would like to return the original packet.

This is the code I have till now:

```
get_message(Packet) ->
    Els = xmpp:get_els(Packet),

    Found =
        case Els of
            [] ->
                <<>>;
            _ ->
                El = find_file(Els, fun(El) ->
                ElementName = io_lib:format("~s",[xmpp:get_name(El)]),
                string:equal(ElementName,"message") end, <<>>),

                Fe = 
                    case El of
                        <<>> -> 
                            Elements = xmpp:get_els(El),
                            lists:foreach(fun(Element) ->
                                FoundElement = get_message(Element),
                                case FoundElement of
                                    <<>> ->
                                        ok;
                                    _ -> 
                                        % stop foreach and return FoundElement
                                        FoundElement
                                end
                            end, Elements);
                        _ ->
                            El
                    end,
                Fe
        end,
    Found.


    find_file(L, Condition, Default) ->
      case lists:dropwhile(fun(E) -> not Condition(E) end, L) of
        [] -> Default;
        [F | _] -> F
      end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I don't need to do all these calculations. these is a method called unwrap_mucsub_message which do exactly what I needed.

```
get_message(Packet) ->
    case misc:unwrap_mucsub_message(Packet) of
        #message{} = Msg ->
            Msg;
        _ ->
            Packet
    end.
```

Answer (score -2):

Whoops, this is erlang!  Here's an erlang solution using `xmerl`, which is erlang's builtin xml parsing module:

xml.xml:

```
<message from="coven@muc.shakespeare.example"
         to="hag66@shakespeare.example/pda">
  <event xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#event">
    <items node="urn:xmpp:mucsub:nodes:messages">
      <item id="18277869892147515942">
        <message from="coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch"
                 to="hag66@shakespeare.example/pda"
                 type="groupchat"
                 xmlns="jabber:client">
          <archived xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:tmp"
                    by="muc.shakespeare.example"
                    id="1467896732929849" />
          <stanza-id xmlns="urn:xmpp:sid:0"
                     by="muc.shakespeare.example"
                     id="1467896732929849" />
          <body>Hello from the MUC room !</body>
        </message>
      </item>
    </items>
  </event>
</message>
```

my.erl:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("./xmerl.hrl").

get_doc() ->
    {ParsedDoc, _Rest} = xmerl_scan:file("./message.xml"),
    ParsedDoc.

get_message() ->
    Messages = xmerl_xpath:string("//message", get_doc()),
    %io:format("~p~n", [Messages]),
    lists:last(Messages).

get_attributes(Node) ->
    xmerl_xpath:string("./@*", Node).

convert_to_map(Attrs) ->

    lists:foldl(
        fun({xmlAttribute,Name,_,_,_,_List,_,_,Value,_}, Acc) ->
            Acc#{Name => Value}
        end,
        #{},  % initial value for Acc
        Attrs
    ).
```

There's also a function called `xmerl_scan:string/1` if you already have your message as a string, for example:

```
{ParsedMessage, _RemainingText = ""} = xmerl_scan:string(Message)
```

You also need the file [xmerl.hrl](https://github.com/yrashk/erlang/blob/master/lib/xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl).

In this function:

```
get_message() ->
    Messages = xmerl_xpath:string("//message", get_doc()),
    lists:last(Messages).
```

`Messages` will be a list containing:

1. One message if there is no nested message, or
2. Two messages if there is a nested message. The nested message will be the last message in the list.

That means that `lists:last()` will return the nested message, or the root message when there is no nested message.

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/xmerl$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> Msg = my:get_message().        
{xmlElement,message,message,[],
            {xmlNamespace,'jabber:client',[]},
            [{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
            2,
            [{xmlAttribute,from,[],[],[],
                           [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
                           1,[],"coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch",false},
             {xmlAttribute,to,[],[],[],
                           [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
                           2,[],"hag66@shakespeare.example/pda",false},
             {xmlAttribute,type,[],[],[],
                           [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
                           3,[],"groupchat",false},
             {xmlAttribute,xmlns,[],[],[],
                           [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
                           4,[],"jabber:client",false}],
            [{xmlText,[{message,2},
                       {item,2},
                       {items,2},
                       {event,2},
                       {message,1}],
                      1,[],"\n          ",text},
             {xmlElement,archived,archived,[],
                         {xmlNamespace,'urn:xmpp:mam:tmp',[]},
                         [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
                         2,
                         [{xmlAttribute,xmlns,[],[],[],
                                        [{archived,2},{message,...},{...}|...],
                                        1,[],
                                        [...],...},
                          {xmlAttribute,by,[],[],[],
                                        [{archived,...},{...}|...],
                                        2,[],...},
                          {xmlAttribute,id,[],[],[],[{...}|...],3,...}],
                         [],[],".",undeclared},
             {xmlText,[{message,2},
                       {item,2},
                       {items,2},
                       {event,2},
                       {message,1}],
                      3,[],"\n          ",text},
             {xmlElement,'stanza-id','stanza-id',[],
                         {xmlNamespace,'urn:xmpp:sid:0',[]},
                         [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
                         4,
                         [{xmlAttribute,xmlns,[],[],[],[{...}|...],1,...},
                          {xmlAttribute,by,[],[],[],[...],...},
                          {xmlAttribute,id,[],[],[],...}],
                         [],[],".",undeclared},
             {xmlText,[{message,2},
                       {item,2},
                       {items,2},
                       {event,2},
                       {message,1}],
                      5,[],"\n          ",text},
             {xmlElement,body,body,[],
                         {xmlNamespace,'jabber:client',[]},
                         [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
                         6,[],
                         [{xmlText,[{body,...},{...}|...],1,[],...}],
                         [],".",undeclared},
             {xmlText,[{message,2},
                       {item,2},
                       {items,2},
                       {event,2},
                       {message,1}],
                      7,[],"\n        ",text}],
            [],".",undeclared}

2> Attrs = my:get_attributes(Msg).
[{xmlAttribute,from,[],[],[],
               [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
               1,[],"coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch",false},
 {xmlAttribute,to,[],[],[],
               [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
               2,[],"hag66@shakespeare.example/pda",false},
 {xmlAttribute,type,[],[],[],
               [{message,2},{item,2},{items,2},{event,2},{message,1}],
               3,[],"groupchat",false}]

3> my:convert_to_map(Attrs).          
#{from => "coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch",
  to => "hag66@shakespeare.example/pda",type => "groupchat"}

4>
```

To get the body tag (or any other nested tag) in the message:

```
get_body(Message) ->
    [Body] = xmerl_xpath:string(".//body", Message),
    Body.
```

To get all the direct child tags of a message:

```
get_direct_children(Message) ->
    xmerl_xpath:string("./*", Message).
```

To get the value of a single attribute of a tag:

```
get_attribute(Attr, Node) ->
    % {xmlObj,string,"coven@muc.shakespeare.example"}
    {xmlObj, string, Value} = xmerl_xpath:string("string(./@" ++ Attr ++ ")", Node),
    Value.
```

---

=== elixir solution ===

You can use [SweetXml](https://github.com/kbrw/sweet_xml) to parse your "packets":

```
defmodule XmlExample do
  import SweetXml

  def sweet(path) do
    File.read!(path)
    |> xpath(~x"//message"l)
    |> Enum.at(-1) 
    |> xpath(~x"//@from")
  end

end
```

The first `xpath()` call returns a (l)ist, i.e. all the matches instead of just the first match.  That list will contain either one or two message tags--depending on the packet.  `Enum.at(-1)` will return the last message tag in the list, which will be either the nested message tag, or the root message tag when there is no nested message tag.  The second `xpath()` call returns the `from` attribute of the message tag, which in the case of your nested packet produces:

```
'coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch'
```

I noticed SweetXml returns a charlist (single quoted string) instead of a double quoted string (which is probably what you want).  If you add an `s` to the second `xpath()` call, then the return value will be a double quoted string:

```
|> xpath(~x"//@from"s)
```

output:

```
~/elixir_programs/xml_example$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> XmlExample.sweet("./lib/xml.xml") 
"coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch"
```

I don't know if there is a better way, but to get all the attributes of a tag you can do this:

```
  def sweet(path) do
    File.read!(path)
    |> xpath(~x"//message"l)
    |> Enum.at(-1)
    |> xpath(~x"./@*"le)
    |> Enum.map(fn {:xmlAttribute,name,_,_,_,_list,_,_,value,_} ->
         {name, value} 
       end)

  end
```

output:

```
[
  from: 'coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch',
  to: 'hag66@shakespeare.example/pda',
  type: 'groupchat'
]
```

In this line:

```
xpath(~x"./@*"le)
```

`./` searches in the current tag, which is the tag returned by Enum.at(-1), and `@*` selects all the attributes. Once again, the `l` is required to make `xpath()` return all the matches(it's super frustrating if you forget the `l`!), and the `e` stand for "entity", which causes xpath() to return the "entities" for each attribute, which look like this:

```
[
  {:xmlAttribute, :from, [], [], [],
   [message: 2, item: 2, items: 2, event: 2, message: 1], 1, [],
   'coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch', false},

  {:xmlAttribute, :to, [], [], [],
   [message: 2, item: 2, items: 2, event: 2, message: 1], 2, [],
   'hag66@shakespeare.example/pda', false},

  {:xmlAttribute, :type, [], [], [],
   [message: 2, item: 2, items: 2, event: 2, message: 1], 3, [],
   'groupchat', false}
]
```

Then the code pattern matches the tuples to pick out the `name` of each attribute and its `value`.

If you would rather get all the attributes in a map:

```
  def sweet(path) do

    attr_entities = File.read!(path)
      |> xpath(~x"//message"l)
      |> Enum.at(-1)
      |> xpath(~x"./@*"le)

    for {:xmlAttribute,name,_,_,_,_list,_,_,value,_} <- attr_entities, into: %{} do
         {name, value} 
    end

  end
```

output:

```
%{
  from: 'coven@muc.shakespeare.example/secondwitch',
  to: 'hag66@shakespeare.example/pda',
  type: 'groupchat'
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're new to Ejabberd. Ejabberd uses its own XML library called fast_xml. IIRC it can be done using fxml:get_subtags/2

Comment: Wow.. Thank you so much for all these details.. but The packet That I have here is already parsed using fast_xml library coming with Ejabberd, I just don't know how to get the nested message from this already parsed xml. I will read your answer one more time and will give you a thumbs up if it give me an idea of how to achieve this. Thanks again for your time you put into this.